# Facebook Connect Integration with Spree Ecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems, spree

I am working on an existing rails application that is built on Spree version 0.11.0 and Rails 2.3.8. I am trying to integrate facebook connect but apparently because of spree application architecture I am not having a lot of success with facebooker and other plugins which are mostly used with Rails Applications..

Any idea how facebook connect is integrated with Spree E commerce ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some extensions to do that on [spree website](http://spreecommerce.com/extensions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=facebook).

But i don't know if they are compatible with Rails 2.3.8 and Spree 0.11.0 but it can give you some example of integration with Spree.